# How can I access a element of a IReadOnlyCollection through it index?

Tags: c#, selenium, listiterator, readonly-collection

I am working with selenium and I am using the function FindElements so I am getting a element that implements IReadOnlyCollection interface. I want to iterate through the list but it seems that IReadOnlyCollection doesnt have any method like Get(int index) or a implementation of the operation [].

I want to avoid transforming the result to a List or to an array since I just want to access the elements to read them.

Currently I don't want to use a foreach since I need to manage an index so I can add those elements to an another array.

This is what I want to do:

```
public void fillMatrix(){
    IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> rows = Driver.FindElements(By.XPath("./*/tr"));            
        IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> elements;
        matrix = new IControl[rows.Count()][];
        for(int i = 0; i < matrix.Count(); ++i){
            matrix[i] = rows[i].FinElements("./td").toArray();                
        }    
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `new IControl`. there are no contructors on interfaces

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use the ElementAt(int) function with the index value.

Here is the MSDN link to the ElementAt(int) function https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 17):

I haven't been using read only collections, but from the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/Hh881542%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) documentation, it looks like it's possible to get element at given index, using `ElementAt` method. It should work like that:

```
IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> rows = Driver.FindElements(By.XPath("./*/tr"));   

int index = 1; // sample

var row = rows.ElementAt(index)
```

You might need to add `using System.Linq;` statement in your class, because `ElementAt()` is an extension method provided by Linq.